# Error 110002 when creating new event via XML API?

Tags: xml, api, events, webex

I am getting following error msg when trieng to create new vent using WebEx xml api.
I am using the same example given in "Cisco WebEx XML API v5.9" create event section.

```
The user or site does not support this meeting type
Exception ID: 110002
```

Please let me know if anybody has any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

delete this line and try again

`<meetingType>x</meetingType>`